# Want to run a python script on a django application

Tags: python, django, web

I'm working on a project that takes a web url and prints a summary of the text contents of the web page. I've written a program that does that in python and now I want to make it a web application so I decided to try django.

I've been reading the official tutorial(I'm not done, I've only gotten up to Models) but when I try to apply what I've learned and actually make the application I find myself lost.

"Where do I actually put the python code that will run on the backend?" I'm not using a database so I don't think it should be in the models.py file. Do I import it in views.py? Should I even be using django? I'm beginning to feel like it's overkill.

Comment: Flask is simpler than Django, try it. And yes, application logic goes into `views.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably have seen in the tutorial, a Django project usually have several apps. Each app typically has models.py, views.py, admin.py, etc. Where to store the script depends on your project structure:

- if only one app needs it, just put the script under the app
- if there're several apps need the script, I mostly like will start an app called "common" or "utils", and put it there
- if the script is used in multiple projects, and updated actively, I will consider make it a standalone Python package. And install it in the project's [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

And where to import the script, also depends:

- if the app is not complicated, no other dependency, views.py is the place to go
- if the app is quite complicated that you even need to separate them into multiple views, I may create a common.py under the app to import the script

About Django or not, it depends our your (potential) project complexity:

- if you project may grow big or you will use Python to write big web project, Django is worth to learn, as it's the most powerful web framework in Python
- if you only need a simple web application that even doesn't need DB, Flask is simpler to learn, as Paulo said